# Transitive Closure of Spacelike Separation

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, topology

Let $S$ be a set of (possibly infinitely many) events in Minkowski spacetime. What would be the necessary and sufficient condition for $S$ (or the elements of *S*) to be such that for *any* $x, y, z$ $\in S$, if *x* and *y* are spacelike separated and *y* and *z* are spacelike separated, then *x* and *z* are also spacelike separated.

That is, is there a way to make sure that *S* is closed under the relation *being spacelike separated*?

Comment: Intuitively I would think $S$ has to be a subset of a spacelike hypersurface.

Comment: possibly useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichain

Comment: @Javier Note: two events on a spacelike surface are not necessarily spacelike-related (example: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/spacetime-distance-between-spacelike-related-events.992261/post-6377987 ). You need an "acausal surface". (See also: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/spacetime-distance-between-spacelike-related-events.992261/post-6379647 )

Comment: @robphy Nice example, I thought something like that might happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Desmos visualization might be helpful:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m1rp8vw6jp

[image: robphy-desmos-acasual]

Let S be these 5 events.
Each event in S is not in the union of the light-cones [boundaries and interiors] of all other events in S.

(One can reformulate the above conditions using light-cone coordinates (u,v) on "rotated graph paper". When reformulated and suitably transformed, the causality expressions can be written in Desmos variables as, e.g., $A_{cau}=\max\left(\left(x-A.x\right)\left(y-A.y\right),0\right)$ )

As I mentioned in the comment to the question,
"being on a spacelike hypersurface" does not guarantee that events on it are spacelike-related.

One needs an "acausal hypersurface".

[image: robphy-spacelikeSurface-withTimelikeRelatedevents]

from https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/spacetime-distance-between-spacelike-related-events.992261/post-6377987

See also this snip from Penrose's *Techniques of Differential Topology in Relativity*
[image: Penrose-Techniques of Differential Topology in Relativity]

from https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/spacetime-distance-between-spacelike-related-events.992261/page-2#post-6379647

While causally-related events can be described by a partially-ordered set (poset),
acausally-related events can be described by antichains ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichain )

Comment: What is the difference between a timeline curve and a causal curve? Is a causal curve either null or timeline?

Comment: One might wish to allow portions of a curve to have a timelike tangent vector or null tangent vector , but nowhere a spacelike tangent vector..  Hence a “causal curve”.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Also I appreciate your diagram. In your diagram, you have only finite (or denumerable) events. Do you think it is possible that a non-denumerable (e.g. continuous) set of events form an achronal hypersurface?

Comment: @Anti-Tachyon Yes. My diagram was to suggest that one can (by extension) have (say) two disconnected segments, or even two disconnected half-lines.

Comment: Would it be also possible that a set of events is achronal but not spacelike?

Comment: @Anti-Tachyon For relations among distinct events, achronally-related (that is, neither timelike-related nor null-related) means spacelike-related. However, for a "hypersurface", the term "a spacelike hypersurface" means the tangent vectors spacelike... for nearby events on this surface, this suggests that they are spacelike related, but for more distant events on this surface, they need not be (as per the counterexample)... So, for "surfaces" the term "acausal" is a necessary restriction for the events on it to be spacelike-related.

Comment: That's very clear, thanks a lot.

Comment: What I was eventually curious about was this: it is said that there is no absolute present in SR because there is no absolute simultaneity in SR. But some people argue that the present doesn't need to be identified with a simultaneous hyper surface, but just a spacelike hyper surface, which is not necessarily 'flat' as a simultaneous hyper surface. I had the impression that there must be something wrong with this idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with what Javier said -- a set $P$ of points that are all mutually spacelike separated, hence a subset of a spacelike hypersurface -- then any additional point, if it is timelike separated from any of $P$ (and if it weren't we could just add it to $P$), must be timelike separated from all of $P$.  So it must fall in the intersection of the light cones from $P$.  So you can create any new spacelike-separated set $P'$ within that intersection.  Then you can repeat, but now using $P \cup P'$ as your reference.

So you end up with a bunch of "spatial patches" where each is in entirely in the light cones of all the others.  Of course a given spatial subset can have as few as one event.

Maybe this isn't the closed form you were looking for and you already knew all this, but it seemed like a cool question so I figured I'd take a shot.

Comment: This is not the case.  Consider (using the obvious coordinate system, $(t,x,y,z)$, $c=1$), $S$ being two points $S=\left\{(0,0,0,0),(0,10,10,10)\right\}$.  These are spacelike-separated.  Now $P = (1,0,0,0)$ is timelike-separated from the first point of $S$ but not the second.